# Matching printf Formatting with iomanip

Tags: c++, floating-point, printf, cout, modifiers

I have some old C code I'm trying to replicate the behavior of in C++. It uses the `printf` modifiers: "%06.02f".

I naively thought that `iomanip` was just as capable, and did:

```
cout << setfill('0') << setw(6) << setprecision(2)
```

When I try to output the test number 123.456, `printf` yields:

> 123.46

But `cout` yields:

> 1.2+e02

Is there anything I can do in `iomanip` to replicate this, or must I go back to using `printf`?

[[Live Example](http://ideone.com/QugWLM)]

Comment: Try taking a look at boost::format().  It supports printf() type syntax for iostreams and is type safe.

Comment: @JonTrauntvein While I appreciate the tip (especially since tons of stuff in boost eventually makes it's way into the standard) I don't include boost wherever possible. And here it seems possible not to include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three C format specifiers map to corresponding format setting in C++ IOStreams:

- `%f` -> `std::ios_base::fixed` (fixed point notation) typically set using `out << std::fixed`.
- `%e` -> `std::ios_base::scientific` (scientific notation) typically set using `out << std::scientific`.
- `%g` -> the default setting, typically set using `out.setf(std::fmtflags(), std::ios_base::floatfield)` or with C++11 and later `out << std::defaultfloat`. The default formatting is trying to yield the "best" of the other formats assuming a fixed amount of digits to be used.

The precision, the width, and the fill character match the way you already stated.

Answer (score 4):

Try [`std::fixed`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/):

```
std::cout << std::fixed;
```

> Sets the `floatfield` format flag for the str stream to fixed.
>
> When `floatfield` is set to `fixed`, floating-point values are written using fixed-point notation: the value is represented with exactly as many digits in the decimal part as specified by the *precision field* (`precision`) and with no exponent part.

Comment: Yup, that got it, what's the meaning of fixed in this context?

Comment: @JonathanMee It uses fixed notation. I updated the post.